# what do you call a logical argument between 2 people who hav personal grudges? Its opposite of Ad Hominem bt not Inverse Ad Hominem. what's it called?

Tags: terminology, argumentation

If A and B already have personal grudges but keep that aside, they are discussing a subject and a conflict erupts argument. Their points are based on the subject only and nothing personal but the heat of the argument is based on their personal enmity. this cannot be called Ad Hominem and it can't be called reverse/inverse Ad Hominem because it's different. So what do we call such a situation of an argument?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a fallacy in the scenario you describe, as both are arguing "based on the subject only and nothing personal. As for whether there is a term for such a situation, you've already identified one, ie: 'A heated argument'.